# PCI Extender and 1GB Ethernet Performance

Tags: performance, hardware, gigabit-ethernet, pci, pci-express

One of my server has 2 PCI slots which has already plugged with 1GB Ethernet cards. I want to add two more 1GB NIC to this server. I've found on ebay [this pci extender](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-Slot-90-Angel-PCI-Riser-Extender-Expansion-Card-1U-2U-/170678601951?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27bd3cc8df).

I want to ask, because I didn't use PCI Extender before. Does PCI extender cause performance lack on GB Ethernets? Will I able to get GB speed on these ethernets if I use PCI extender? Is one PCI slot able to run 3 ethernet cards at full performance?

Or is there any PCI extender on PCI-ex for performance? Or do I have to change motherboard to add more NICs?

---

[image: photo]

The essence of the product's description:

- Expands PCI slots from 1 to 3.
- Installs PCI device at 90° angle to the riser card.
- Compliant with PCI 32bit 33Hz.
- One end is three PCI female and another end is one PCI male.
- CN1, CN2, CN3 & CN4 ports available for PCI slot 1 & 3. (CN1, CN2, CN3 & CN4 cables included)
- PCI slot 2 does not need to be configured. PCI slot 1 & 3 need to be connected to CN1, CN2 & CN3, CN4.

Comment: Are you looking for more NICs, or more 1GbE ports? There's a difference. Also, *why* do you want more ports? What level of utilization do you expect?

Comment: We have a iSCSI SAN system with 2 nodes. The nodes have 3 nic, one for Heartbeat, one for iSCSI connection and one for LAN connection. I want to double iSCSI and LAN connections by adding more NICS. We need to increase bandwidth of the SAN. I plan to use LAGG or NLB on LAN connection, and MPIO on iSCSI.

Comment: Time for a new MB then. Sorry. The board you've got will never do better than about 2Gbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That item connects to a PCI (note not PCI-e/PCIe) 33Mhz, 32 bit bus.

That bus is only capable of handling 1,067 megabit per second - so even if all the right stars aligned you'd only ever be able to support a single GigE interface on that port at 100% utilisation. In reality it would slow down just this one card - let alone three of them.

I don't know about PCIe extenders, not much experience in that really but this PCI one is bit of a mistake in my opinion. Might it not be better to buy a new systemboard?

Comment: Thanks. It means, there is no solution except buying a new mobo.

Comment: Note: that board does NOT connect to **ONE** PCI Slot; It connects to **THREE** PCI slots on the MB and "extends" them upward for a rackmount case configuration. It will not add more PCI slots to a MB.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've found PCI-E to PCI adapter but it is too expensive. It has its own case. As I plan to extend two of node PCs, it doubles the price.

Comment: Holy F***K Chris - you're right, wow what a weird/crappy product, just wow